# The truth behind human urine and marking territory?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry

So some years ago, I remember watching a survival show in which the host said that human males produce a type of chemical in the urine that animals such as wolves can acknowledge as a territory marker. The host also said that women do not produce it, and therefore cannot mark territory in the same way men can.

Would this be accurate? Would the results of this change at all if the individual was a fully transitioned transgender person?